# Swift - AlamofireImage download multiple URLs and display in CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, alamofire, alamofireimage

I would like to download multiple URLs from string in array, and display images in `collectionView`. I succeed to display four images (4 visible cells on my screen) and when I scroll, that begins the download of the 2 other images.

I want that these 6 images are downloaded in the same time (and I don't have to scroll for beginning the other download). After this, I want to display the total time spent to download and display images in my `collectionView`.

What I am doing wrong ?

Here is my code :

```
import UIKit
import AlamofireImage
import Alamofire

class ViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource {

    var players = [
        ["image_Name":"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1420768255295-e871cbf6eb81?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&s=4b94ef340bd7f6cac580fbc76af326af"],
        ["image_Name":"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1465411801898-f1a78de00afc?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&s=149d27223217c0fa63c7dd8f1e8d23f6"],
        ["image_Name":"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1466853817435-05b43fe45b39?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&s=a3b629b7e0c4f710ce119f219ae5b874"],
        ["image_Name":"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1467404899198-ccadbcd96b91?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&s=66eef8db7a0aa4119c6c8d7ba211f79f"],
        ["image_Name":"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1470322346096-ecab3914cab7?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&s=83863ba23662871baf6434c6000e00bd"],
        ["image_Name":"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1473624566182-509e437512f4?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&s=54c3ec6d1fee824d62e6fa76676ddf17"]
    ]
    var methodStart = Date()

    @IBOutlet weak var mycall: UICollectionView!
    var selectedIndex=[Int]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }


    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.players.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell:playerCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "playerCell", for: indexPath) as! playerCell

        let url = URL(string:self.players[indexPath.row]["image_Name"]!)
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
           methodStart = Date()
        }
        Alamofire.request(url!).responseImage { response in
            //            debugPrint(response)
            //            print(response.request)
            //            print(response.response)
            //            debugPrint(response.result)

            if let image = response.result.value {
                cell.playerImage.image = image
            }
        }

        if indexPath.row == self.players.count - 1 {
            let methodFinish = NSDate()
            let executionTime = methodFinish.timeIntervalSince(methodStart as Date)
            print("Execution time: \(executionTime)")
        }

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: after download ,update image in main queue and setneedslayout property for image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem in your code -**

you said you want those 6 images to be downloaded at the same time and when user scrolls the 5th and 6th image should display immediately. but this is not happening because the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` function for the 5th and 6th cell called when you scroll. this is the default behavior and you cannot invoke this before user scrolled.

**Quick fix solution -**

Download all the images outside `cellForItemAtIndexPath` function, like in either `viewDidLoad` or `viewDidAppear` by looping the array of players and then reload the collection view after completion of download of the last one.

**Permanent and best solution -**

Implement lazy loading and caching of images using either [Heneke](https://github.com/Haneke/Haneke) or [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) to display image in cells. And use `prefetch` option in those libraries to fetch images before they were shown in cells. To use prefetch option you need to loop through the array and pass the urls to the fetching and storing functions of the library and just load image in cell according to the syntax of that library and it will manage the displaying of image when it downloaded and you don't have to worried about that.

Answer (score 1):

When you are dealing with network calls, you should update UI in main queue. One more valid point i want to add here is Alamofire has a special library for image download/resize. Please have a look at [AlamofireImage Library](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage)

```
Alamofire.request(url!).responseImage { response in
            if let image = response.result.value {
               DispatchQueue.main.async {
                  cell.playerImage.image = image
                  cell.playerImage.setNeedsLayout()
               }
            }
        }
```